Wrap callback function with cancellation mechanism into Swift async/await?
I'm working on wrapping a function from a Kotlin Multiplatform (KMP) codebase in Swift. While my current implementation works, it feels quite verbose and boilerplate. I'm looking for a more elegant, compact, and idiomatic solution in Swift.
Here's a simplified version of my current code:
func asyncWrap() async throws -> Int {
    
      let cancellationQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "cancellation.queue", qos: .background)
      let cancellationSemaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
    
    
      return try await withTaskCancellationHandler {
        return try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
          AsyncKt.kotlinMultiplatformCallback(onCancellation: { cancel in
            cancellationQueue.async {
              // Await cancellation signal
              cancellationSemaphore.wait()
              cancel()
            }
          }, completionHandler: { result, error in
            cancellationSemaphore.signal()
            if let ret = result?.intValue {
              continuation.resume(returning: ret)
            } else {
              continuation.resume(throwing: error ?? fatalError())
            }
          })
        }
      } onCancel: {
        // Handle task cancellation
        cancellationSemaphore.signal()
      }
    }

Any suggestions or improvements? Would be greatly appreciated.
